# Нужно сделать слайдер в слайдере

Tags: jquery, slider, carousel, slick.js

Искал долго карусель на jquery, но именно такой нигде не нашел. Думал, что можно сделать с slick, но там не подключишь именно группировку. Может быть кто нибудь может подсказать плагин?

P.S. Слайдер как на этом сайте в разделе "Посмотрите на кухни сделанные нами"

[Слайдер](http://lux-5.ru)

Comment: owl-carousel - https://codepen.io/washaweb/pen/KVRxRW

Answer (score 1):

slider-slick вам поможет в решение данной задачи, сам недавно реализовывал, у меня на третьем горизонтальном слайде был подключен вертикальный из нескольких слайдов!

```html
      <div id="slider-gorizont" class="slider-gor">
                <div class="sl-g">First</div>
                <div class="sl-g">
                    <div id="slider-vertical" class="slider-vertical">
                        <div class="sl-v"></div>
                        <div class="sl-v"></div>
                        <div class="sl-v"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="sl-g">Third</div>
                <div class="sl-g">Fourth</div>
      </div>
```

```
Инициализируем слайдеры:
```

```
  function slickSl() {
  $('#slider-vertical').slick({
    infinite: true,
    vertical: true,
    arrows: false,
    dots: true
  }); 

 $('#slider-gorizont').slick({
    infinite: true,
    arrows: false,
    verticalSwiping: true,
    dots: true
    });
}
```

первый будет горизонтальным, а во-втором слайде будет еще и вертикальный.
Со стилями, я думаю, сами справитесь)

Comment: неплохо было бы дополнить ответ примером кода